# SQL: using mulitiple SELECT statements / retrieving same field twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Two tables:

```
person(name,person_id)
lesson(teacher_id, student_id, time, place)
```

I want to retrieve the teacher name, students names, the time and place

So like so:

```
Teacher|Student|Time|Place
ms bla | fred  | 12 | UK
ms bla | Jim   | 12 | UK
mr ttt | john  | 10 | UNI
```

etc..

So how do I select `person_id` twice using `WHERE` to match to the `teacher-id` & `student_id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join to the same table multiple times by using an [alias](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm) to rename the table ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f4c/1)):

```
select
    teacher.name as Teacher,
    student.name as Student,
    lesson.time,
    lesson.place
from
    lesson
join
    person teacher on teacher.person_id = lesson.teacher_id
join
    person student on student.person_id = lesson.student_id
```

The `lesson` table is linked to `person` table (aliased as `teacher`) by `teacher_id` = `person_id`.  Then the lesson table is linked to `person` table again (aliased this time as `student`) by `student_id` = `person_id`.  By using the aliases, we can reference the column `name` for each alias to get the respective teacher and student names.

Comment: Thanks, took me a sec but i got it now.